# How long does it take to hear back from the faculty hiring committee after an initial screening interview?

Tags: job-search, tenure-track, interview, psychology

I'm currently on the hunt for a job and I applied for several tenure-track psychology faculty positions. I did initial Zoom interviews with a couple of places (15 - 30 minutes long). It's been about a week since the interview, and I am getting nervous.

How long does it normally take to hear back from the hiring committee after an initial screening interview? My advisor said it really varies but I would feel much better if I have at least a rough estimate. Also, do they actually tell you if you are not going to be invited to the on-campus job talk?

Answer (score 3):

It can take a while. Don't expect anything in a week. There may be other candidates. They need to schedule internal discussions. They need to get some buy-in from administration. If it goes on for a month, ask about whether there are updates.

And keep on the hunt for other positions. Don't close out any other options until it is definite.